$a, b, c$ are all real numbers with different values, given $a=ab+c, b=bc+a, c=ca+b$, find value of $a+b+c$.
This question is from my maths Olympiad book which I found it hard to solve it. The question is shown below:

(Beijing Math Competition Training Question) If $a, b, c$ are all real numbers with different values, and given
$$\begin{cases} a=ab+c~~~~ (1) \\ b=bc+a~~~~ (2) \\ c=ca+b ~~~~(3)\end{cases}$$
Find the value of $a+b+c$.
(Answer given in the book: $3$)


My attempts:
As $a,b,c$ are all distinct, we can find that all values of $a,b,c$  can’t be $0$.
$(1)+(2)+(3),$ we can find that
$a+b+c=ab+bc+ca+a+b+c$
where $ab+bc+ca=0$
$$a=ab+c \implies a(1-b)=c ~~~(4)$$
$$b=bc+a \implies b(1-c)=a~~~~(5)$$
$$c=ca+b \implies c(1-a)=b~~~~(6)$$
$(4)\times(5)\times(6)$,
$$abc(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)=abc$$
$$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)=1$$ ( We can divide $abc$ on both sides of the equation as we know that the value $a, b, c$ can’t be $0$.)
$$1-(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ac-abc=1$$
$$a+b+c-ab-bc-ac+abc=0$$
$$a+b+c+abc=0$$
I think I almost done solving this question, but I still need some hints to find the value of $abc$. Any help will be appreciated.

You don't need the value of $abc$.
Multiplying by $c,a,b$ in $(1), (2), (3)$ respectively we obtain
$$ac=abc+c^2,$$
$$ab=abc+a^2,$$
$$bc=abc+b^2.$$
Since $ab+bc+ca=0$, summing the equations, it follows
$$0=3abc+(a^2+b^2+c^2)=3abc+(a^2+b^2+c^2+2[ab+bc+ca])=3abc+(a+b+c)^2$$
As $a+b+c+abc=0$, solving for $abc$, we deduce that
$$a+b+c=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}$$
Then $a+b+c$ is $0$ or $3$, but if $a+b+c=0$ then $abc=0$. Thus,
$$ac=c^2,$$
$$ab=a^2,$$
$$bc=b^2,$$
and $0=a^2+b^2+c^2$ which gives $a=b=c=0$, which is not possible as the values of $a,b,c$ are distinct.

From $(1), c=?$
Replacing the value of $c$ in $(2), b=b(a-ab)+a, a=\dfrac{-b}{b^2-b-1}$
$\implies c=\cdots=\dfrac{-b(1-b)}{b^2-b-1}$
From $(3),$  on replacement of the values of $a,c$
$$b(b^3-3c^2+\cdots)=0$$
As $b\ne0, b^3-3c^2+\cdots=0$
By symmetry, $a,b,c$ are the roots of $$t^3-3t^2+\cdots=0$$
Can you apply Vieta's formula?
